# do not echo commands to comint-mode buffer

Tags: comint

I have a comint managing a subprocess and I want to send a huge text payload to it that the user doesn't need to see (it's a multi-page configuration string that must be provided this way).

Text sent to the comint is normally echoed to the buffer, is there a way to suppress this?

Comment: How do you send the payload to comint at the moment? `comint-send-string` doesn't echo it anywhere on Emacs 22.3.1 and 25.1.1.

Comment: oh, doh! @Wieland you're absolutely right... the subprocess is echoing it back at me and I didn't realise.